# In angular 6, How to make url with '-' but not with '/'

Tags: angular, routes

I'm a beginner in Angular and StackOverflow.

I want to use a URL with a `-` character as the parameter separator.

For example; A URL could be `http://localhost:4200/nf-clarkzkent` where `clarkzkent` is the `:username` parameter:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: ':username', component: NewsfeedComponent, data: [{ username: true }] }
];
```

Now the problem is I have to create another URL like `http://localhost:4200/cmpgm-clarkzkent` where `clarkzkent` is the parameter.

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [      
   { path: ':username', component: NewsfeedComponent, data: [{ username: true }] },
   { path: '??', component: ChannelComponent, data: [{ ?? }] },
];
```

Comment: but what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to define one more route like http://localhost:4200/cmpgm-clarkzkent.
here "clarkzkent" is my dynamic data.

Comment: Why do you need it ? What is exactly you want to achieve with logic like this?

Comment: i think you should go with `/` like `http://localhost:4200/nf/clarkzkent` `http://localhost:4200/cmpgm/clarkzkent` this is the best practices.

Comment: @Subhajit but my application requirement is to have - instead of /

Comment: "but my application requirement" -- this is what i need to know. As @GurpreetSingh said, you can try url like /nf/abc. Now if your req. is like nf-clarkzkent needs to be parsed and do some logic on the parsed values, you can do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm a beginner in Angular and StackOverflow.

Welcome to Angular and StackOverflow. You are asking what I think is an advance level question, and even I will have a bit of difficulty giving an answer because usually this takes a bit of trial and error to get working.

You need to implement a URL serializer and tell Angular to use your custom URL serialize instead of the default one. The new serializer will convert dashes `-` to slashes `/` so that Angular thinks the two are the same.

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer

I can not test the following code, but it might look like this.

```js
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
class CustomUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string) : UrlTree {
        return super.parse(url.replace(/-/g,'\\'));
    }
}
```

The above is very simple, but it will also rewrite dashes in query parameters (but for now this is good enough).

After you have the custom URL serializer you have to tell Angular to use it instead of the default.

```js
@NgModule({
    providers: [
       {provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer}
    ]
    // ....
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What will happen now is Angular will think all *dashes* in the URL are the same as *slashes* and you can configure your router like you would normally. Except you use `/` instead of `-` in the paths.

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [      
   { path: 'nf/:username', component: NewsfeedComponent, data: [{ username: true }] },
   { path: 'cmpgm/:username', component: ChannelComponent, data: [{ ?? }] },
];
```

The above will match routes and allow you to define parameters separately with a *dash*, but the only side effect is that all routes work when a *dash* is used instead of a *slash*. So you will want to improve your custom URL serializer to be more specific, but you should get the idea of how this work from this example.

Comment: @ImteyazAhmad Did u got solution...???? Am searchig for this now. Please reply...

Comment: This is working perfectly with routerlink routing. But When page get reload. Its redirecting to the Homepage component.